# How can I enable session in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, session

I would like to enable session in Symfony2, but I don't know how can I do that.

I set my config file like this:

```
#app/config/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        name:             session
        cookie_lifetime:  0
        cookie_httponly:  true
```

But it seems to my session is still disabled and not started. I tested this code in my controller:

```
echo ( session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE )
    ? "Session is not started!"
    : "Session OK";
```

And it return "Session is not started!". It works only when I set:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

But this is very ugly solution, especially that I am working in Symfony2. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to acitivate it, it's set per default with symfony.

The default entry is this:

```
framework:
    session: ~
```

You also don't need to start a new session (in fact you'll receive an error because it's already started from symfony).

**15.04.2016 Edit:**

The Syntax is a bit different by now

Controller

```
$session = $this->get('session');
```

Twig

```
app.session
```

**Old Version:**

You just need to get the session in your controller from the Request!

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
```

That's all.

In Twig you can access it via

```
app.request.session
```

Answer (score 0):

In my current project I've enabled session like this and it works fine:

(under framework option)

```
session:
        handler_id: ~
        cookie_domain: .st.dev
        name: SFSESSID
        cookie_lifetime: 0
        save_path:            "%kernel.cache_dir%/sessions"
        gc_divisor: 2000
        gc_maxlifetime: 86400
```

you can also look at this [documenation page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session)

Answer (score 0):

In app/config/config.yml, under framework section, you must have a session item :

```
framework:
    # ...
    session: ~
```

Just have a look at : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of Session in Symfony2 is bit different:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

// store an attribute for reuse during a later user request
$session->set('foo', 'bar');

// in another controller for another request
$foo = $session->get('foo');
```

Answer (score -1):

Sessions are automatically started when you read/write data in it if you use a recent version of Symfony2.

However, you can force it to start by instanciating a session variable and start it:

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

You should take a look at the doc. Be careful, Symfony sessions are not the same thing as native sessions.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html